# Deserialize json Array to get value to filter jqgrid data in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I get this error :
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'KETABMA_MVC.Models.SearchFilter' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

from the  line below:

```
  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchFilter>(filters);
```

I have an JsonArray data Like This:

```
[{"YEAR_ABBR":"1398_1398"},{"YEAR_ABBR":"1397_1397"},{"VAHED_ID":"909"}]
```

That it comes from the below method:

```
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                $("#loaderDiv").show();
                var myformdata =JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());
               alert(myformdata);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    datatype: 'JSON', 
                    data: { filters: myformdata , _search: true },
                    url: '@Url.Action("Get_Contracts_Steps", "Home")',

                    success: function () {
                        $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                                            }
                })
            })
        })

    </script>
```

And I want to send it to jqgrid manageMultiFieldSearch method as multiple filter